# Azure AD B2C - Redirect the user to the login page based on the directory it belongs when using custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

My application contains users from B2B and B2C directory. It is using Azure B2C Login which is created using custom policy for this purpose. Currently, it displays the B2B directory button in B2C Login screen. In my application we can identify if the user belongs to B2C or B2B directory.

My requirement is that if the user is identified as B2B user then it should redirect to the B2B login screen directly instead of B2C login and clicking on B2B Sign in button.

Is there any way by which I can accomplish this in my application?

Comment: What have you done so far for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a `<Domain>` to your B2B `<ClaimsProvider>`. Then,  pass it in as a `domain_hint` which will take the user directly to that IDP.

This is how Facebook is set up [in a starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/3b4898fec3bf0014b320beffa6eb52ad68eb6111/SocialAndLocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L444) and you could try it there and copy the required elements.

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
    <!-- The following Domain element allows this profile to be used if the request comes with domain_hint 
       query string parameter, e.g. domain_hint=facebook.com  -->
    <Domain>facebook.com</Domain>
    ...
</ClaimsProvider>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Omer, this works fine. I am using MSAL library for authentication,  `var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage' }); ` How do I pass this parameter when using msal library?

Comment: Also another thing when using direct url the token is not stored in localstorage due to which the MSAL object redirects to the B2C login page.